# Is there a Japanese word or phrase for half-human, half-snake?

Tags: grammar, terminology

I am looking for a Japanese term that would describe a half human, half snake creature like the Medusa from the original Clash of the Titans. There are yokai, that are similar, but do not match what I am looking for. I'm leaning towards using 大蛇人間 orochi ningen or daija ningen, but I'm not sure if that would be grammatically correct.

Comment: Googling for `"半人半蛇" "は"` (adding the は to filter for Japanese hits, excluding Chinese-only hits) [turns up a reasonable number of results](https://www.google.com/search?q="半人半蛇"+"は"), some with images.  Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: 大蛇人間 is technically correct but I feel Medusa is not a 「大」蛇. You may want to use 蛇女【へびおんな】 instead. 半人半蛇 ("half-human, half-snake") is also okay, but it's closer to a description (no-adjective) rather than the name of a species.